# Return a User and Message in Parse Query

Tags: parse-platform, xamarin

Updated:

I am able to get to here, but I still can't return the username.

```
public async void getMessagesFromGroup1(string sGroupObjectId) {

        try{

            var innerQuery = ParseObject.GetQuery("Message").WhereEqualTo("Group", ParseObject.CreateWithoutData("Group", sGroupObjectId)).Include("User"); //.Include("Category");

            IEnumerable<ParseObject> MyFirstResults = await innerQuery.FindAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("made it past the query");

            foreach (var result in MyFirstResults)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("made it into forloop");

                var category = result.Get<string>("Content");
                Console.WriteLine ("The message  is......... " + category);


                var userObject = result.Get<ParseObject>("User");
                var user = result.Get<string>("username");
                Console.WriteLine ("The from user......... " + user);
            //  return category;

            }

        }
        catch(Exception exception){

            Console.WriteLine ("- " + exception.Message.ToString());
        }

    }
```

I am building a message board application using Parse and Xamarin.

I need to query a table of Messages and return the Content of each message and the Username of the person who posted the message.

This should return a list.

I am able to retrieve the Message.Content, but not the User information.

How can I return the username from user table?

I appreciate your advice and thoughts.

Current Code:

```
    public async void getMessagesFromGroup(string sGroupObjectId) {


        // OBJECT ID:  ejphwBr3UX

        var query = from message in ParseObject.GetQuery("Message")
                where message["Group"] == ParseObject.CreateWithoutData("Group", sGroupObjectId)
            select message;

        IEnumerable<ParseObject> results1 = await query.FindAsync ();

        //  List<ParseObject> list = results.ToList;


        List<ParseObject> list = results1.ToList();


        Console.WriteLine ("testing");
        try
        {

            Console.WriteLine ("test" + list[0].Get<string>("Content") +  " ");

        }
        catch  (Exception exception){

            Console.WriteLine ("- " + exception.Message.ToString());

        }
        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it


    }
```

Comment: The exception is 
- The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

this is how I did it... I had to convert the Parse Object into a parseuser

```
public async void getMessagesFromGroup1(string sGroupObjectId) {

        try{

            var innerQuery = ParseObject.GetQuery("Message").WhereEqualTo("Group", ParseObject.CreateWithoutData("Group", sGroupObjectId)).Include("User"); //.Include("Category");

            IEnumerable<ParseObject> MyFirstResults = await innerQuery.FindAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("made it past the query");

            foreach (var result in MyFirstResults)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("made it into forloop");

                var Content = result.Get<string>("Content");
                Console.WriteLine ("The message is......... " + Content);


                var userObject = result.Get<ParseUser>("User");
                var user = userObject.Username;
                Console.WriteLine ("The message is from user......... " + user);
            //  return category;

            }

        }
        catch(Exception exception){

            Console.WriteLine ("- " + exception.Message.ToString());
        }

    }
```